# How to change the notification timeout in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, notifications

IMHO the notifications in GNOME (3) are hidden very quickly. Of course, it depends on the user, how fast he/she can read that notifications or so. So is there any way to change how long the notifications are displayed before they are hidden?

Quickly searching through dconf I could not find any setting for this.

---

Cross-posted from [Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/106333/how-to-change-the-notifiation-timeout-in-gnome/).

Answer (score 2):

As for now the answer seems to be: [There is a ticket for this.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783719)

It does not seem possible yet, as [a user on Ask Fedora found out](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/106333/how-to-change-the-notification-timeout-in-gnome/?comment=106398#comment-106398).